# Updating circle pack layout via keyboard

Tags: javascript, d3.js, keyboard, circle-pack

I have a circle pack layout that represents some data from a json file. When I click on the left-right arrows on the keyboard I want the pack layout to update. I managed to update the position of the circles but not the radius. Could you please take a look at the code below? My circle pack is not really hierarchical, I mean I just have one parent, the circle with id 'coreCircle' and then all the children inside.

Thanks,
RM

```
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.someField;
  })
  .children(
    function children(d) {
      return d.someArray;
  });

var corevis = d3.select('#svgCoreGroup');

// Creating the circle packed core
var gNodes = corevis.data([json]).selectAll("g.node")
  .data(pack.nodes, function(d) {return (d.children ? "coreCircle" : d.name)});

// Remove
gNodes.exit().remove()

// Update
corevis
  .data([json]).selectAll("g.node")
  .data(pack.nodes, function(d) {return (d.children ? "coreCircle" : d.name)})
  .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node"; })
  .attr("id", function(d) { return d.children ? "coreCircle" : null; })
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
  .selectAll("circle")
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.children ? coreSize : d.r; });

var node = gNodes
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node"; })
  .attr("id", function(d) { return d.children ? "coreCircle" : null; })
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.children ? coreSize : d.r; })
```

Comment: I actually solved the issue: I was binding the new data in the wrong spot. Binding the new data after the .selectAll('circle') worked like a charm.

Comment: If you've answered your own question, don't forget to mark it as resolved.

Comment: Is that the correct solution in your opinion? By the way I have problems in transitioning the inner radius of the pie.. :(